# What is the use of an empty abstract class?

Tags: java, oop

I want to know that is there any use of empty abstract class in Java? If so, what is it?

Comment: No use.  It is the moral equivalent of a marker interface.

Comment: @Stephen, What is the use of "marker interface" ?

Comment: what-is-the-purpose-of-a-marker-interface: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023068/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-marker-interface

Comment: does "empty" also preclude having parent classes and interfaces?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An empty `abstract class` is very much equivalent to an `interface` except that it can extend a `class`

```
abstract class myAbstractClass // extends anotherClass implements anInterface
{

}

interface myInterface // extends anotherInterface
{

}
```

This pattern is called **Marker interface** and SO has a lot of good data about it already: [What is the purpose of a marker interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023068/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-marker-interface)

Comment: or extend a class and "implement" one or more interfaces. Kind of like a junction type.

Comment: yes, actually wanted to point out difference at compile time.

Comment: In my book interfaces `extends` other interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

you can only inherit from one abstract class. Then this is useful to avoid inheritance.

Comment: How is avoiding inheritance useful?

Comment: what behaviour does an empty class have?

Comment: What's 'final' about an abstract class?

Comment: @EJP: an abstract class can have final methods (but an "empty" one cannot).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sometimes you need a base class for implement polymorphism.

Comment: Yes, sure, sorry. But the main difference is that you can implement some code in your base class, or define some attributes :)