# Why we can't instantiate abstract class of non abstract methods in it?

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class, abstract, abstraction

We know we can't instantiate an abstract class as it is incomplete. But why can’t we instantiate a class with no abstract methods in it which is marked as abstract? Is there any reason for that?

Comment: You can using an anonymous instance: `MyAbstract myAbstract = new MyAbstract(){};`

Comment: `Is there any reason for that ?` - ain't being *abstract* enough? You mark a class as *abstract* to mark that its instantiation is *prohibited* - IMO it's a quite reasonable reason.

Comment: Awesome, never knew that.  So, this can be done only in case when we don't have any abstract method in that class, ryt? and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

An abstract class is created for the sole purpose of inheritance. Hence, its instantiation is prohibited weather it has all the required method definitions or not.

Answer (score 0):

such kind of class may be used as `Interface`.
you should also go through the concept of `marker interface`

also see [What is the use of an empty abstract class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12633782/what-is-the-use-of-an-empty-abstract-class)