# What's the minimum type requirement for a materialized collection?

Tags: c#, .net

If I'm serializing a collection of objects, what's the minimum type to guarantee that the collection is materialized (and not the result of an expression)?

e.g.. this should not be possible:

```
var message = new MyMessage {
  Recipients = someCollection.Select... // <- this can't be deserialized without calling ToList()
}
```

I know IList would do the job, but want to know if this is the *minimum* requirement.

Comment: What Type is `someCollection`?  Usually the minimum is `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @ErikPhilips `IEnumerable` are allowed to lazy-load/execute, so its not that.

Comment: Well *technically* that would be a return type, I should have just asked what the collection is.  `AsEnumerable` will return a lazy loaded collection, and `ToList()` will return an explicitly loaded list, but it that would depend on EF vs Linq2Sql vs Linq2Entities.  They aren't all quite the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I know IList would do the job

Actually, it would not.  No interface can ever possibly have such a guarantee, because I can always make an implementation of that interface that defers materialization of any query until some of the interface methods are called.  Now, by *convention*, a type implementing `IList` would be a materialized collection, and not something deferring work, but that is not a guarantee.

To have a guarantee you'll need to use a concrete type rather than an interface, accepting an array, `List`, etc.

Of course one option that you have is to accept an interface such as `IEnumerable` and then *materialize it into a collection yourself* (possibly as a 3rd overload with overloads for arrays and lists to avoid the need to re-materialize those) because if you've materialized it yourself then you *know* it's not deferring execution.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't.** Whether a collection is materialized or a query is ultimately an implementation detail that is not exposed via any normal public API. However, if you want to be reasonably sure given common types, you can use `ICollection<T>`.

`ICollection<T>` requires that the `Count` be available. `IList<T>` further requires that you can access elements by index. Since you don't appear to need anything beyond `IEnumerable<T>`, I'd recommend `ICollection<T>`, e.g.

```
public ICollection<Recipient> Recipients { get; set; }
```

It may also be useful for you to create an `IMaterialized` or `IMaterializedEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>` [marker interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1023078/781792) and class(es) that implement it, if ensuring that a collection is materialized is more important than being able to easily use built-in types and methods.