# Is there a way to chain multiple "is" statements in c# to check whether an instance is in a collection of class types?

Tags: c#, class, types, operator-keyword, keyword

```
if(item is classA || item is classB || item is classC || ...)
```

is there a way to write that line of code more elegantly? I think this can be done but how do you create a collection of types (not instances) so that you can check whether the type of item is inside of that collection?

Comment: You can create a `List<Type>` and fill it with `TypeOf(ClassA)`, etc...

Comment: Can you add an interface to each of them? Generally discouraged as just a marker, but it does work. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023068/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-marker-interface

Comment: What should happen inside the if block?

Answer (score 3):

With C# 9 you can do this:

```
if (item is classA or classB or classC) {}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements for more info.

Answer (score 2):

To create a collection of types, use `typeof()`:

```
new[] { typeof(Class1), typeof(Class2), typeof(Class3) }
```

This creates a `Type[]`. However, `is` can't be used on `Type` instances. You can use [`IsAssignableFrom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=net-5.0) instead. Note that just comparing if the type of `item` is equal to the array elements is not enough to replicate the behaviour of `is` - `is` does more than that. It checks the inheritance hierarchy, and [a bunch of other stuff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#the-is-operator) too.

Combine that with `Any`, you get:

```
if (new[] { typeof(Class1), typeof(Class2), typeof(Class3) }.Any(x => item.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(x))) {

}
```

This certainly doesn't look too much more elegant than your original, but if you have a *lot* of types to check, it will eventually be shorter.

Note that unless all the types have some common members, checking whether an object `is` any of those types isn't very useful. There isn't anything extra that you suddenly can now do, once you know that `item` is *one of* these types. You still can't safely cast it to a specific type.

If all the types *do* have some common members, consider writing an interface with all the common members, and making those types implement that interface. This way you just need to check if `item is` that interface!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is more elegant, but if you want to check whether the item's type is part of a collection you could do

```
if (new [] { typeof(classA), typeof(classB), typeof(classC) }.Contains(item.GetType()))
{

}
```

Following the comments, to replicate the `is` behaviour, you could do

```
if (new[] { typeof(classA), typeof(classB), typeof(classC) }.Any(x => item.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(x))) 
{

}
```

Comment: @Llama The question is "how do you create a collection of types (not instances) so that you can check whether the type of item is inside of that collection?". I can't see how it doesn't answer it?

Comment: You'd need to use `.IsAssignableFrom` to be equivalent.

Comment: I don't disagree, I just strictly answered his question (he didn't mention inheritance nor his wish to stick to the `is` behaviour) but I get your point and edited my answer.