# How to restrict an object to one of its interfaces for type testing?

Tags: c#, interface, type-testing

I have four interfaces:

```cs
public interface IBasicBoat
{
    Hull BoatHull { get; set; }
}

public interface ISailBoat : IBasicBoat
{
    List<Sail> Sails { get; set; }
}

public interface IMotorBoat : IBasicBoat
{
    Engine Motor { get; set; }
}

public interface IGenericBoat : ISailBoat, IMotorBoat
{
}
```

and one class:

```cs
public class GenericBoat : IGenericBoat
{
    public Hull BoatHull { get; set; }

    public List<Sail> Sails { get; set; }

    public Engine Motor { get; set; }
}
```

I want my algorithm to work differently on `ISailBoat`s and `IMotorBoat`s.

Say I have these two objects:

```cs
    ISailBoat z_objSailBoat = new GenericBoat()
    {
        BoatHull = new Hull(),
        Sails = new List<Sail>()
    };

    IMotorBoat z_objMotorBoat = new GenericBoat()
    {
        BoatHull = new Hull(), 
        Motor = new Engine()
    };
```

and this method:

```cs
    public void CheckBuoyancy(IBasicBoat p_objBoat)
    {
        // [...]
    }
```

that is called twice: `CheckBuoyancy(z_objSailBoat)` and `CheckBuoyancy(z_objMotorBoat)`.

Inside `CheckBuoyancy()`, I want to be able to tell whether `p_objBoat` is an `ISailBoat` so I can check the sails.

I've tried

```
    if (p_objBoat is ISailBoat z_objSailBoatToCheck)
    {
        // do something with z_objSailBoatToCheck.Sails
    }
```

but both `z_objSailBoat` and `z_objMotorBoat` pass that test.

1. Why does `z_objMotorBoat is ISailBoat` return true?
   (1a. Is it because `z_objMotorBoat` is created as a `GenericBoat`, or is it more complicated?)
2. How can I check whether `p_objBoat` is an `ISailBoat`?

The obvious solution to 2. would be to create more classes like `SailBoat` and `MotorBoat` so I'd have two different constructors, but I'd like to avoid that. (If only because my actual case is noticeably more complicated.)

Comment: An `IGenericBoat` has sails. If you define an `ISailBoat` as a "boat with sails", then an `IGenericBoat` is certainly an `ISailBoat`. (The `is` operator is doing dynamic casting - there is not much more to it). To answer question 2 - using `is` is the way to do so.

Comment: IGenericBoat is ISailBoat AND IMotorBoat, because you inherit from both interfaces. So it doesn't matter what type you declare on your local variable, you don't change what it actually is.

Comment: A `GenericBoat` object implements `IGenericBoat`, which extends `ISailBoat`, so every `GenericBoat` is an `ISailBoat`. The fact that you haven't set its `Sails` property doesn't change that. It still has that property. If you want objects to only be one or the other of `ISailBoat` and `IMotorBoat` then you need two different classes that implement one or the other of those interfaces.

Comment: As a side note, and to add to what others have already written, using an empty (A.K.A marker) interface is usually the wrong thing to do. I'm not sure if that's just for the same of your example or if it's a part of your actual code, but if its the latter, [you should strive to avoid it.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1023068/3094533)

Comment: How about using [explicit interface implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation)?

Comment: @user240738: I see your point, though I had thought that with technical objects it might go otherwise. Tim Schmelter and jmcilhinney have given further detail as to why not, so I now understand perfectly.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : Well and concisely put. Thanks!

Comment: @jmcilhinney: that's what I feared. Thanks for the explicit response.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Noted. I'm not sure `IGenericBoat` is a marker interface since it isn't actually empty (having the properties of all three others), that being said, and I've had at least one occurrence where having such an interface was actually useful (no space for details, and I'm not going into debate on that).

Comment: @Oliver: Very interesting! I'm not sure how relevant it is to my current situation (if only because I'm working with properties here, not methods), but I'll do well to remember it for a later opportunity.

Comment: The `IGenericBoat` interface doesn't add anything to the interfaces it inherits, so... and also, I wrote "usually", meaning that sometimes it is the correct thing to do (I've also used marker interfaces myself in a few occasions).

Comment: @Jean-DavidLanz: If you read further in the article, you can also explicit implement properties, not only methods.

Comment: Indeed! I only saw a way to make a difference between a property and a method, but it surely follows that one can declare two different properties. My bad! I should also have said that what I was looking for was a way to tell which interface type an object was, it being understood that they had different properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why does z_objMotorBoat is ISailBoat return true? (1a. Is it because z_objMotorBoat is created as a GenericBoat, or is it more complicated?)

***The reason is that GenericBoat implements both interfaces and runtime will always evaluate it that way.***

2. How can I check whether p_objBoat is an ISailBoat?

***You might check that by revisiting the code.***

Interfaces:

```cs
public interface IBoat
{
    Hull BoatHull { get; set; }
    Buoyancy CheckBuoyancy();
}

public interface ISailBoat : IBoat
{
    List<Sail> Sails { get; set; }
}

public interface IMotorBoat : IBoat
{
    Engine Motor { get; set; }
}
```

Classes:

```cs
public abstract class Boat : IBoat
{
    Hull BoatHull { get; set; }

    public virtual Buoyancy CheckBuoyancy() {
        // Calculate buoyancy if both boat types use same algorithm.
        // If not you might want to change virtual modifier to abstract to force each concrete type to implement its own calculation.
    }
}

public class MotorBoat : Boat, IMotorBoat
{
    Engine Motor { get; set; }

    public override Buoyancy CheckBuoyancy() {
        // In case you need to use different way to calculate buoyancy
    }
}

public class SailBoat : Boat, ISailBoat
{
    List<Sail> Sails { get; set; }

    public override Buoyancy CheckBuoyancy() {
        // In case you need to use different way to calculate buoyancy
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
IBoat boat1 = new SailBoat()
{
   BoatHull = new Hull(),
   Sails = new List<Sail>()
};

IBoat boat2 = new MotorBoat()
{
    BoatHull = new Hull(), 
    Motor = new Engine()
};

var boatBuoyancy1 = boat1.CheckBuoyancy();
var boatBuoyancy2 = boat2.CheckBuoyancy();

if(boat1 is ISailBoat sailBoat) {
   var sailsCount = sailBoat.Sails.Count();
}

if(boat2 is IMotorBoat motorBoat) {
   var horsePower = motorBoat.Motor.HorsePower;
}
```