# What is the meaning of "this" in C#

Tags: c#

Could anyone please explain the meaning "this" in C#?

Such as:

```
// complex.cs
using System;

public struct Complex 
{
   public int real;
   public int imaginary;

   public Complex(int real, int imaginary) 
   {
      this.real = real;
      this.imaginary = imaginary;
   }
```

Comment: why not look up at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx)? "The `this` keyword refers to the current instance of the class."

Comment: See MSDN:[this (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: vlad - Why not post on stackoverflow ?

Comment: @Vlad - A question that's valid for a lot of the questions asked for SO. The point of SO is to be a place that can be used as a reference. Firstly, not everyone knows about `MSDN` (so pointing them there is a good idea). Secondly, the OP has given context. Valid question IMO.

Comment: It is very difficult to search for common words like "this". Have you actually gone to the MSDN site and typed in "this" to see what the search results are? It is about as difficult as finding out what the ? and ?? mean in if-then statements, or => in a lambda expression.

Comment: I think the question is valid, though I certainly don't see it hard to find references to `this` via google: `c# this` returns plenty of good results (msdn included).

Comment: @DOK: googling "this c#" gives MSDN as the first link.

Comment: Sigh. I guess you could pretty much Google anything that we have here at SO. Maybe we should just give up. And especially discourage n00bs.

Comment: Now that you know what it means, don't use it unless you have to. Unnecessary use of the `this` keyword drives me insane.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of 'this' keyword in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013857/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-keyword-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Here is the details on Microsoft -[LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this)

Answer (score 20):

The `this` keyword is a reference to the current instance of the class.

In your example, `this` is used to reference the current instance of the class `Complex` and it removes the ambiguity between `int real` in the signature of the constructor vs. the `public int real;` in the class definition.

[MSDN has some documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) on this as well which is worth checking out.

Though not directly related to your question, there is another use of `this` as the first parameter in [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods). It is used as the first parameter which signifies the instance to use. If one wanted to add a method to the `String class` you could simple write in any static class

```
public static string Left(this string input, int length)
{
    // maybe do some error checking if you actually use this
    return input.Substring(0, length); 
}
```

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 3):

When the body of the method

```
public Complex(int real, int imaginary) {
    this.real = real;
    this.imaginary = imaginary;
}
```

is executing, it is executing on a specific instance of the struct `Complex`. You can refer to the instance that the code is executing on by using the keyword `this`. Therefore you can think of the body of the method

```
public Complex(int real, int imaginary) {
    this.real = real;
    this.imaginary = imaginary;
}
```

as reading

```
public Complex(int real, int imaginary) {
    assign the parameter real to the field real for this instance
    assign the parameter imaginary to the field imaginary for this instance
}
```

There is always an implicit `this` so that the following are equivalent

```
class Foo {
    int foo;
    public Foo() {
        foo = 17;
    }
}

class Foo {
    int foo;
    public Foo() {
        this.foo = 17;
    }
}
```

However, locals take precedence over members so that

```
class Foo {
    int foo;
    public Foo(int foo) {
        foo = 17;
    }
}
```

assigns `17` so the variable `foo` that is a parameter to the method. If you want to assign to the instance member when you have a method where there is a local with the same name, you must use `this` to refer to it.

Answer (score 2):

As most answers are mentioning " the current instance of a class", the word "instance" may be difficult for newbies to understand. "the current instance of a class" means the this.varible is specifically used in the class where it is defined, not anywhere else. Therefore, if the variable name also showed up outside of the class, the developer doesn't need to worry about conflicts/confusions brought by using the same variable name multiple times.

Comment: You got that gap <> which was really missing.

Answer (score 1):

`this` references the instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Nate and d_r_w have the answer. I just want to add that in your code specifically the this. does in deed refere to the member of the CLASS to distinguish from the arguments to the FUNCTION. So, the line

```
this.real = real
```

means assign the value of the function (in this case, constructor) parameter 'real' to the class member 'real'. In general you'd use case as well to make the distinction clearer:

```
public struct Complex
{
    public int Real;
    public int Imaginary;
    public Complex(int real, int imaginary)
    {
        this.Real = real;
        this.Imaginary = imaginary;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't actually need `this` if your argument names differ from field names. But for the OP's example, using `this` is compulsory.

Answer (score 1):

> The this keyword refers to the current
>   instance of the class and is also used
>   as a modifier of the first parameter
>   of an extension method.

[image]

[this (C# reference) - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
[C# Keywords - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx)

Comment: Why include a picture of code? Stack Overflow has had the ability to include text formatted as code since the beginning...

Answer (score 0):

this is a variable which represents the current instance of a class. For example

```
class SampleClass {
public SampleClass(someclass obj) {
obj.sample = this;
}
}
```

In this example, this is used to set the "sample" property on someclass obj, to the current instance of SampleClass.

Answer (score 0):

Refers to current instance of class