# In C#, I came across a use of the key word "this" that I did not understand

Tags: c#, constructor, tree, this

I was looking in the tree structure and I found a constructor 
(in the Tree class) that looked like this:

```
public Tree(T value, params Tree<T>[] children)
: this(value)
{
   foreach (Tree<T> child in children)
   {
     this.root.AddChild(child.root);
   }
}
```

can someone explain to me what does ": this(value)" mean?

Comment: It's the call to the **constructor overload** of `Tree` that takes only `value` as argument.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270774/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thank you sir . Now i remember that i have seen this and i'm going to read through it again .Im sorry for losing your time.

Comment: In general, `this` refers to the same class you're currently in. You don't see it a lot because it's implied.. e.g. you don't see a method in the person class say `this.Name = "Nikolai"` because `Name = "Nikolai"` will do just fine. Same for methods: when one method in your class wants to call another in the same class it could say `this.DoSomething()` but you're more likely to write simply `DoSomething()`.. So why use it with constructors? Well.. there isn't any way to refer to a constructor by name because they don't have one in the same way that a method or property has a name so the..

Comment: ..convention is to use `this(arguments to constructor here)`

Answer (score 2):

It's called [constructor chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814953/c-sharp-constructor-chaining-how-to-do-it). Another constructor of the class is called before that constructor. Basically it's `base` but with a constructor of the current class instead of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

The usage of `this` here is calling another constructor overload on the class and passing `value` as an argument.