# AddRange adding to which of my collections?

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance, observablecollection, addrange

Upon looking into the following code I am unable to figure out the  this.AddRange(hoteltasks); on line 21.

I want to know to which collection the AddRange method adds the elements of hoteltasks.

```cs
public class HotelViewModel : ObservableRangeCollection<RoomViewModel>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // It's a backup variable for storing TaskViewModel objects
    private ObservableRangeCollection<RoomViewModel> hoteltasks = new ObservableRangeCollection<RoomViewModel>();

    public HotelViewModel()
    {
    }

    public HotelViewModel(Hotel hotel, bool expanded = false)
    {
        this.Hotel = hotel;
        this._expanded = expanded;

        foreach (Room task in hotel.Tasks)
        {
            hoteltasks.Add(new RoomViewModel(task));
        }
        if (expanded)
            this.AddRange(hoteltasks);
    }
 
    private bool _expanded;
    public bool Expanded
    {
        get { return _expanded; }
        set
        {
            if (_expanded != value)
            {
                _expanded = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Expanded"));
                  
                if (_expanded)
                {
                    this.AddRange(hoteltasks);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Clear();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AddRange` is called on `this`, so the contents of `hoteltasks` are added to `this`.

`this` refers to the current instance of `HotelViewModel`. Since line 21 is in the constructor, `this` refers to the newly created instance of `HotelViewModel`. There is also a second occurrence of `this.AddRange(hoteltasks);` further down the code in the setter of `Expanded`. There, the current instance is the instance on which you are accessing `Expanded`. For more info, see [What is the meaning of "this" in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6270774/5133585)

Although `this` is an instance of something called "HotelViewModel", which doesn't sound like a collection, it *is* in fact a collection. This is because it is declared to inherit from [`ObservableRangeCollection<RoomViewModel>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.communitytoolkit.objectmodel.observablerangecollection-1?view=xamarin-community-toolkit-sdk), so it has all the behaviours of a `ObservableRangeCollection<RoomViewModel>`, such as being able to have `RoomViewModel`s stored in it, and being able to have a range of `RoomViewModel` added to it.

Comment: What if when I declare another variable of ObservableRangeCollection<RoomViewModel>  name as hoteltasksnew then in which variable this.AddRange  will add the contents of hoteltasks as now there are two variable one is hoteltasks and hoteltasksnew .

Comment: You didn't seem to have understood my answer. Before you "declare another variable", `this.AddRange(hoteltasks)` ***does not add*** the contents of `hoteltasks` to `hoteltasks`. That would actually throw an exception (but that's another story). `this.AddRange` adds the contents of `hoteltasks` to `this`, which is itself a `ObservableRangeCollection<RoomViewModel>`. Try to convince yourself that `this` is also a `ObservableRangeCollection<RoomViewModel>` by reading my last paragraph.

Comment: Got it...Thanks for you prompt response

Answer (score 0):

HotelViewModel  is a ObservableRangeCollection, which is a List-Type

If you create  somewhere a new instance

```
HotelViewModel myNewModel= new HotelViewModel(hotel,true);
```

then myNewModel is the List (this.AddRange(hoteltasks);)

Try

```
var t = myNewModel.ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, It was very helpful to understand further by this. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

`ObservableRangeCollection` inherits from `ObservableCollection`, which inherits `Collection<T>` which implement ICollection interface.

`Collection<T>` have protected Items property;

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.items?view=net-6.0

So `this.AddRange()` adds items in `Items` propery